# Blacklist/whitelist applications in Linux

Tags: linux, security, executable

I would like to learn about solutions/alternatives for managing execution access to applications in Linux-based systems (specifically Fedora flavours).

I already researched into possibilities like Integrated Measurement Architecture, fapolicyd or Microsoft Integrity Policy Enforcement.

I am more interested in solutions with more capabilities than simply comparing the hash value of the executable against a known list, but at this point pretty much any suggestion is welcome.

The purpose for which I need this mechanism is enforcing the users of certain machines (which I own and manage) to only be able to execute code that I have authorised them to.

Comment: Hello. Could you update your question with a use case which you need the solution for? Without it your request might look like a [request for learning materials, which would be outside the scope of what SE is for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or [considered too broad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @RomanRiabenko sure, I updated the question

Comment: How do your requirements go outside the access control offered by user groups where only certain groups can execute p, only certain other  groups modify q etc and then assigning to each user the appropriate groups.

Answer (score 0):

fapolicyd is capable of doing this.

> fapolicyd is a userspace daemon that determines access rights to files
> based on a trust database and file or process attributes. It can be
> used to either blacklist or whitelist file access and execution.

- from `man 5 fapolicyd`

Per `man 5 fapolicyd.rules`, you can control execution via hash, path of the file, a whole directory, source device, mime types, or file hash. This access control can be further locked down by the subject, specifying uid/gid, executable, etc.

Red Hat has fapolicyd documentation available [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening). The aforementioned man pages also have decent documentation.